# Copay wallet problem: "Could not update Wallet: Network connection error"

Tags: spv, bitcore, bitpay, copay

Apparently BitPay's servers must be down because I can browse the internet but my copay wallet is stuck in this error:

[image]

Is there any way to know if it's really an issue on their end and if they're looking at it? Do they have a status twitter page or something?

(This kind of things are really unfortunate, which can hinder adoption. I guess my only way to avoid it would be to run my own bitcore node, right?)

Answer (score 1):

After some hours, it started to work again. Apparently bitpay's servers were down for a bit.